# Variable type object

Tags: object-oriented

Is there a language with something like the following construct?

```
var_type(TYPE_1, TYPE_2,..., TYPE_N) obj;
```

and now its possible to:

```
TYPE_17 staticTypeVariable17;
obj = staticTypeVariable17;

TYPE_3 staticTypeVariable3;
obj = staticTypeVariable3;
```

without `obj` being a pointer of some base class and with no need for casting if the types used are from the predefined set.
So basically an object that can switch it's type amongst a predefined set of types.

Comment: Something like python? python variables are not typed, only values are.

Comment: If you need that, then you are doing something wrong and you should learn something about OOP, generics and abstractions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construct you are referring to is called a [discriminated union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) and is part of quite a few languages and can be created in more.

Among the languages that support discriminated unions are C++, Visual Basic, ML and Haskell and those are just the languages that popped up in the wikipedia article.